# How to set only two image for single row in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have tried with story board to create a collection view with image. Totally i have 6 images. So per row i need to show 2 images. And no gap should be in between two images in one row. when i open in all screen, it should be two image for single row. how to add this in my code:

**ViewController.m :**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    NSArray *arrayImages;
    NSArray *arrayLabel;

}
@synthesize MycollectionView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self MycollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self MycollectionView]setDelegate:self];

    arrayImages =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png",@"image6.png", nil];
    arrayLabel = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1",@"image2",@"image3",@"image4",@"image5",@"image6", nil];
}
// datasource and delegate method
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;

}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrayImages count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *Cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[Cell myimage] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[Cell myLabel]setText:[arrayLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];


    return Cell;

}
```

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myimage;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want only 2 cells visible on the screen? Then you need to set the size of the UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

To set dynamically use collection view delegate methods

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/2, height: collectionView.frame.size.width/2)
}
```

It creates collection view cell of equal width and height i.e. Square

Comment: Thats what i am asking , whether we can implement in code or how to do that interface in storyboard

Comment: Hey just wait... I will post a image

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample Image]
For Swift 5:
First set the collectionview's cell size from the sizeInspector,
then add the following code. Check image for clarification

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
     // do some codess..
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selected Cell: \(indexPath.row)")
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
  return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/2, height: collectionView.frame.size.width/2)
 }
```